# Image viewer or browser for large images

Tags: imagery

I have some big images. I'm looking for an easy way to browse and view them. Currently I'm using Preview.app on OS X, but it wasn't designed for these types of images.

My images are, for example:

- .JP2, 42 MB, 50,000 x 30,000 pixels
- a 3.4 GB TIF
- something in NITF format

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenEV comes with FWTools, 
seems OK to me but I load 300 MB images into QGIS easily and deal with them there. So I can recommend it only from casual use.

http://OpenEV.sourceforge.net

Includes NITF

and is built with GDAL

Answer (score 3):

I've found [WxGIS Catalog](http://code.google.com/p/wxgis/wiki/ScreenShots) to be quite good, it provides a fast interface and supports many spatial formats due to its use of GDAL -- many of the fast image viewers won't support spatial formats beyond those which are standard image types.

Comment: +1 It is so helpful to provide reasons for a recommendation as well as indicating possible strengths and limitations.

Answer (score 2):

Gigapan is very good with large images

http://www.gigapan.org/embedding/?window_height=747&window_width=1440

designed for panoramic images

Try the main page to view some submitted images
http://www.gigapan.org/

supports Windows and OS X